# Schwarzschild radius violation?

Tags: black-holes, time-dilation, event-horizon, causality, tidal-effect

I have a puzzling question concerning the crossing of the Schwarzschild boundary. If a person (lets say in some large robust spaceship) flys quickly between 2 super-massive rotating black holes within crossed Schwarzschild radii, what would the effects be? The apparent Schwarzschild boundary to the person would change closer to each hole but would an observer see them cross? Would tidal effects be canceled and what time dilation would there be?

Answer (score 1):

The Schwarzschild radius is just a distance.

What you really are asking is what happens if there are two crossed event horizons. An event horizon is a boundary where nothing on one side can affect the other side; in particular things that cross from the other side to that side will never escape. If you have two closed event horizons that overlap, that indicates that they act as a joint event horizon nothing can escape.

In practice, placing two black holes close together will cause their event horizons to expand - sometimes faster than light: they are after all not physical things - and merge.

Exactly how close they have to be depends a fair bit on how the holes move and rotate, and there are no analytic formulas for it. just some very hard numerical relativity simulations. Even if they are not merging the exact tidal effects and time dilations will be hard to calculate.

Comment: “*... event horizons to expand - sometimes faster than light*” +1, but could you please clarify what you mean by “faster than light” in reference to the horizon? As observed from any distance (even if just the Planck length away), the speed of light at the horizon is zero.

Comment: Consider a ring of black holes as wide as you want; move them together - at some point it seems you should get a torus-shaped black hole. But the topological censorship theorem shows that you cannot send a light signal through the hole in the torus to the other side, it will always be captured (!). The horizon expanding to cover the hole can move as fast as needed. The apparent speed of light signals as measured by remote observers doesn't have anything to do with it.